# Sharing URLs with Twitter

Tags: twitter

I have some issues when sharing URLs with Twitter.

I share http://google.com using following URL

https://twitter.com/share?text=hello&url=http://google.com

output is given below.
[image]

But when I try to share http://google
with following URL

https://twitter.com/share?text=hello&url=http://google

Twitter can't correctly display the sharing URL as given below.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these mixed up, it's the other, proper way around.

- https://twitter.com/share?&text=hello&url=http://google.com - *will* work.
- https://twitter.com/share?&text=hello&url=http://google - *won't* work.

As to your edit which seems to have switched them around, the answer is this. It shouldn't work with the one you seemingly think is 'broken' because you're not providing a valid URL for the URL parameter (one with a specific [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)).

Answer (score 1):

think there was a mistake there but assuming the iusse is "http://google" isn't working is the issue?

If so thats not an issue, I wouldn't imagine this would be picked up as a url as I would not class this as valid, i'm sure theres a format mentioned somewhere. Twitter can't provide a link to an invalid url as that would be bad practise.

Also the ampersand "&" directly after the query string "?" is redundant, you should remove that

Answer (score 1):

When you was sharing `http://google.com with url it was valid url format` but when you try to share `http://google twitter found a invalid url format` and it not accept it. If you want to share http://google type url then try

```
http://twitter.com/?status=hello http://google
```

It will accept this.

thanks